# Will I still have an item in my collection if i trade a copy of it to a friend

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So in Star Wars the old Republic there is a collections part of the game. If you pay extra cartel coins you can even have the items you purchased account wide. Well I own a copy of the descendant's heirloom dual bladed lightsaber. If I were to create another character and extract a copy of said lightsaber, will it still be in my collections for me to use at any time?

Comment: Short answer: if you pay cartel coins to unlock account wide, you can "extract" as many copies of that item as you want on all your characters; All items are however bound to pick up

Comment: Vahx is right. No item obtained from Collections can be traded or mailed or sold.